# How to create Graphs from CSV data

Tags: excel, libreoffice-calc

Data is formatted like this:

```
TESTID    Result    Timestamp
a         1         1
a         1.2       1.02
a         1.9       2.61
b         1         0
b         0.2       0.99
```

Now I'd like to create line plots, two in this case (a and b). Data range is defined by the first column, the second column indicated X values and the third Y values.

I'm looking for a way to do this in libreoffice calc, but Excel or even gnuplot are fine, as long as they work.

---

Edit:

To clarify, this is not a simple single line plot. In this case, there are 2 lines one for 'a' and one for 'b'. The number of lines is not predefined, there might be any number of lines.

---

Edit:

I'm so sorry if this was too simple to ask, but I wasted too much time on this before I found the easy, non scaling way to do this.

Comment: You should be able to do an xy plot with your favourite spreadsheet program. If you have never used one, this is the wrong place to ask for help. Btw. what you show are NOT Comma Separated Values.

Comment: Please don't judge beforehand. This is not an easy thing to do, my coworkers told that it's impossible to program libreoffice to do this and I should do it in matlab instead. I don't have matlab, neither do I know how to use it properly. And yes, that is not CSV. I wrote it like that so that it's easier to read. I already found one hackish way to do it, but it didn't seem like the proper way.

Comment: Note that in this case I want two lines in the graph, one for a and one for b. Also the number of lines is not set in stone, there might be up to 100 lines.

Comment: Also, if you look around, there are plenty of other questions about programming excel on this site. None of them have people complaining that the questions don't belong here.

Comment: This is the SIMPLEST task with any office suite. If you think otherwise, please edit your post to explain properly what a solution should actually DO. Automatically handle other kind of data?

Comment: So you want a script that automatically splits your data into parts a,b,c..., and then plots each of those with an xy line plot into one graph, because you will be plotting a lot of different datasets and don't want to split them by hand every time? That'd be a reasonable request, but it is not what you asked for.

Comment: You could make extra columns for each a,b,c line with formulas like `=IF(A1="a";B1;"")` and then have the graph use the extra columns as data sources for each line.

Comment: @Lyrl: If you return a `#N/A` instead your `""` then the chart will skip those values instead interpreting them as 0. Assuming `D1` = "a" and `E1`= "b", then `=IF($A2=D$1,$C2,NA())`. In the chart column B is X and columns D and E are Y.

Comment: Charts in programs are so _yesterday_. Use Google Charts and you don't have to install anything.https://developers.google.com/chart/?hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but works.

Essentially this is the same as one of the comments, but with a bit less work.

Create a pivot table out of the data, with:

- TESTID as columns
- Timestamp as rows
- Result as values

Then create a XY Scatter (Not the pivot table graph in excel). Use the content of the Pivot table to plot data, skip the Sum at the end and use the matrix with empty cells instead.

LibreOffice does everything correctly, but with excel there is one further step.

You need to tell Excel what to do with the empty cells, right-click on the graph and choose "Select Data..." a dialog opens, click "Hidden and Empty Cells", select "Connect data points with line" or whatever you prefer, click OK and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT: Ooops, just found that this solution was already proposed by @Lryl in comments... maybe i should keep the answer as illustration`? please comment...*

With LibreOffice, without PivotTable, but same approach:

1. Import csv:

   [image]
2. In `D2`, enter: `=IF($A2="a";$B2;"")`; drag down to handle all `a` values from column `B`;
3. Copy formula from `D2` to `E2`, change to: `=IF($A2="b";$B2;"")`; drag down to handle all `b` values from column `B`;
4. Now, you have the same as the Excel pivot table. Add column headers `a` and `b` to `D1` / `E1`:

   [image]
5. Select `C1:E6`;
6. Create X/Y scatter plot, with sorted x values:

   [image]

This results in:

[image]